# ASP and C# - DropDownList Selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hello Stack Overflow Community
I have a question regarding an ASP `DropDownList` which doesn't seem to produce the correct selected output when I request the `SelectedItem.Text` String in my C# code.
The following is my ASP code for the DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRecalllayaway" AccessKey="z" 
runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="20px" 
Width="130px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And here is a portion of my C# code which successfully fires on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
public void ddlRecalllayaway_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    String selected = ddlRecalllayaway.SelectedItem.Text;
    // Things I want to do with the string which has been selected
}
```

When I use the `DropDownList` in-browser and select an item other than the top one, the event fires successfully, however I've added a break-point and hovered over the `selected` variable to find that it says the top item in my `DropDownList` rather than the item which I have selected.
Any helpful suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!
**Edit:**
My question is different from the 'possible duplicate' because the accepted answer is referring to the `AutoPostBack` property being set to true. However, in mine, I have already set it to true yet it isn't working.

Comment: How are you binding the event handler to the control? You set the `AutoPostBack` property on the control but not the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` one.

Comment: The event will only trigger if the selected index is changed. You need to make sure you are selecting an index and not just changing the displayed text. By default the first item in the list will be selected (at index 0) which explains why selecting it again wouldn't change the index or trigger the event....

Comment: I just added `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRecalllayaway_SelectedIndexChanged"` to the ASP code. This still does not work. The event fires perfectly fine, however it's just referring to whichever item has been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite common when the contents of the `DropDownList` is being bound again on post back, which will happen before your `SelectedIndexChanged` event, thus resetting the selected index.

Make sure your binding code is on the first page load only.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // bind drop down list here
}
```